# If $i$ is recurrent then expected recurrence time is the limit of $\frac 1 {(1-s)p_{ii}(s)}$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, stochastic-processes, generating-functions, markov-process

> Theorem: i is recurrent then $\mu_{ii}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty nf_{ii}^n = \lim_{s\rightarrow 1^{-}} \frac 1 {(1-s)p_{ii}(s)}$

Proof:

Let $i$ be recurrent.

Then, note:

\begin{align}
& \lim_{s\rightarrow 1^{-}} F_{ii} (s))=\lim_{s\rightarrow 1^{-}} \sum_{n=0}^\infty f_{ii}^n s^n \\[10pt]
& \Longrightarrow F_{ii}(\approx 1^{-})=\sum_{n=0}^\infty f_{ii}^n=1 \\[10pt]
& \Longrightarrow \lim_{s\rightarrow 1^{-}} ( 1-F_{ii} (s)) =0
\end{align}

Again, observe:

\begin{align}
& F_{ii} (s)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty f_{ii}^n s^n \\[10pt]
\Longrightarrow & F_{ii}'(s)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty nf_{ii}^n s^{n-1}
\end{align}

so,

$$F_{ii}'(\approx 1^{-})=\sum_{n=0}^\infty nf_{ii}^n \approx \lim_{s\rightarrow 1^{-}} F_{ii}' (s)=\lim_{s\rightarrow 1^{-}} \sum_{n=0}^\infty nf_{ii}^n s^{n-1} $$

How to I then conclude that $F_{ii}'(s)=\lim_{s\rightarrow 1^{-}} \frac{1-F_{ii} (s)}{1-s}?$

Vital hints are appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand what your question is. "How do I conclude that ...": this is the definition of derivative. (I suppose you meant $F_{ii}^{'} (1-)$ on the left side.

Comment: This was what i was looking for.